Python Code not prompting questions ? - Cipher Selection Code
the code runs, but for some reason its not prompting the questions I set up, it just sits idle. ive been used to coding in C/C++ for a while so I'm still getting into the growing pains on using python.
Ask my name, last name, then asks me what cipher I want to use, then the text I want to encrypt.
here is the code:
def caesar(message, shift):
    """
    Encrypts or decrypts a message using the Caesar cipher.
    """
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    encrypted_text = ''

    for char in message.lower():
        if char in alphabet:
            index = alphabet.find(char)
            new_index = (index + shift) % 26
            encrypted_text += alphabet[new_index]
        else:
            encrypted_text += char
    return encrypted_text

def vigenere(message, key, vshift, encrypt=True):
    """
    Encrypts or decrypts a message using the Vigenere cipher, incorporating an additional shift (vshift).
    """
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    result = ""
    key_index = 0

    for char in message.lower():
        if char in alphabet:
            index = alphabet.find(char)
            base_offset = alphabet.find(key[key_index % len(key)].lower())
            # Adjusting offset with vshift
            if encrypt:
                offset = (base_offset + vshift) % 26
                new_index = (index + offset) % 26
            else:
                offset = (base_offset - vshift) % 26
                new_index = (index - offset) % 26
            result += alphabet[new_index]
            key_index += 1
        else:
            result += char
    return result

morse_dict = {
    'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
    'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.', 'O': '---', 'P': '.--.',
    'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-',
    'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..', '0': '-----', '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--', '4': '....-',
    '5': '.....', '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.', '.': '.-.-.-', ',': '--..--',
    '?': '..--..', "'": '.----.', '!': '-.-.--', '/': '-..-.', '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', '&': '.-...',
    ':': '---...', ';': '-.-.-.', '=': '-...-', '+': '.-.-.', '-': '-....-', '_': '..--.-', '"': '.-..-.',
    '$': '...-..-', '@': '.--.-.', ' ': '/'
}

def to_morse_code(message, encryption=True):
    
    morse_code = ''
    for char in message.upper():
        if char in morse_dict:
            morse_code += morse_dict[char] + ' '
    return morse_code

def from_morse_code(morse_code, encryption=True):
        
    message = ''
    morse_code = morse_code.split(' ')
    for code in morse_code:
        for char, morse in morse_dict.items():
            if morse == code:
                message += char
    return message


def bacon_cipher(message, encrypt=True):
    # Implement Bacon cipher encryption/decryption
    return "Bacon Cipher Placeholder"


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            yerfn = input('What is your first name? ')
            yerln = input('What is your last name? ')

            if not (yerfn.isalpha() and yerln.isalpha()):
                raise ValueError("Name must contain only alphabetic characters")

            initial2 = yerln[0].upper()
            print(f'Hello {yerfn} {initial2}, before we begin...')
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Error: ", e)
    
    while True:
        try:
            print("Select the cipher method:\nA: Caesar Cipher\nB: Vigenere Cipher\nC: Bacon Cipher\nD: Morse Code")
            choice = input("Your choice (A/B/C/D): ").upper()
        
            if choice not in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
                raise ValueError("Invalid choice")
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Error: ", e)

    if choice != 'D':
        text = input("Enter the text to encrypt/decrypt: ")

    result = None
    if choice == 'A':
        shift = int(input("Enter the shift for the Caesar cipher: "))
        result = caesar(text, shift)
    elif choice == 'B':
        key = input("Enter the key for the Vigenere cipher: ").lower()
        vshift = int(input("Enter cipher shift: "))
        result = vigenere(text, key, vshift, encrypt=True)  # Assuming encryption by default
    elif choice == 'C':
        result = bacon_cipher(text)
    elif choice == 'D':
        morsechoice = input("Choose an option:\n1: Text to Morse code\n2: Morse code to text\n-1: Quit\n")
        if morsechoice == '1':
            message = input("Enter a message to convert to Morse code: ")
            result = to_morse_code(message)
        elif morsechoice == '2':
            morse_code = input("Enter a Morse code sequence to convert to text: ")
            result = from_morse_code(morse_code)
        else:
            print("Quitted successfully")
            return

    if result is not None:
        print("Result:", result)


There's nothing here related to Cypher. I think you mean "cipher".

You have a main() function, but you are not calling it.  Unlike C/C++, main is just another function and is not called automatically.  You probably want to add if __name__ == "__man__": / main() at the end.

that was it, thanks now i can run/debug the code in peace. forgot you have to call the main fuction, unlike C/C++ (now i feel kinda dumb hahaha).

provide a minimal reproducible example in the future. we don't need all of your different encryption schemes.  The problem would have been revealed if you literally removed the entire selection of encryption mechanism at the bottom.   99% of the code you posted was irrelevant.  Keep that in mind in the future
